# Variable scope js - return initial assignment instead of changed

Tags: javascript, variables, scope, return-value

Have next script:

```
function clicker(){
var linkId = "[id*=" + "link]";
var butnId='initial';       
    $j(linkId).click(function(){
        var postfix = $j(this).attr('id').substr(4);
        butnId = '#' + 'butn' + postfix;
        });

return butnId;

}
```

Function output is 'initial' value.

How to return actual value of variable ***butnId***,after it had been transformed within click function?

Comment: it's not clear, from your code, what you actually want to achieve here. when `clicker` returns, it will not have executed the `postfix`-part. all it did was to say that that code should be executed *when a certain link is clicked*. there is no loop to transform the value. what is it that you want for `clicker` to achieve?

Comment: I want to extract postfix from clicked link , and on its basis i will know what link should be clicked next - it's ID is butnId.
Seems that I think from Java point, when i initialize variable, transtom it within,e.g. loop, and it's value is changed.
So i will try you proposals Below. thanks.

Comment: I want to add, that i perform click on UI and butnId is really changed,but it's unchanged as function output, so it doesn't go out of click function scope and stay unmutable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code inside the function passed to `click` doesn't get executed until the element is clicked.

You probably need the caller of `clicker` to pass in a callback function that can then be called by the click function (assuming you don't want to hardcode the required action into the click function itself):-

```
function clicker(callback){
var linkId = "[id*=" + "link]";
var butnId='initial';       
    $j(linkId).click(function(){
        var postfix = $j(this).attr('id').substr(4);
        butnId = '#' + 'butn' + postfix;
              callback(butnId);
        });

return butnId;

}
```

Which likely can be refactored to:-

```
function clicker(callback){
var linkId = "[id*=" + "link]";
    $j(linkId).click(function(){
        var postfix = $j(this).attr('id').substr(4);
        callback('#' + 'butn' + postfix);
        });    
}
```